# OSGI server Addin programming and Domino security not working

Tags: java, osgi, acl, lotus-domino

i am building a Domino OSGI Server Plugin that has to access different applications when called from the web.
So far it is working. I get the application given in the parameters and get json back to the caller dependand on the call parameters which include the database id. And some other stuff.

Next step was to try and check if a user that is calling anonymous and has no access to a specific application will get an answer from the server.

I found that the server does always answer and that the acesslevel to that application which is locked and not accessible to the user when he tries to open it direct in the web browser is always level 6 
That is because the service runs with the rights of the server if you look at it regardless of the user logged in.

I checked this with:

```
 directoryDatabase = s.getDatabase("",dbName");
 pw.println("Common userName = " + s.getCommonUserName() + " effective user name " + s.getEffectiveUserName() + "<BR>";
```

and some other print and this is always the result:

```
Common user Name = geniusgermany effective user nameCN=geniusgermany/O=genius
File really opened = fakenames10k.nsf fakenames10k.nsf
File current access level = 6
```

So the question is how do i have to construct the plugin to make sure that it works with the users access level. not with the one of the server?

Answer (score 0):

OK the first thing is to use

```
import com.ibm.domino.osgi.core.context.ContextInfo;   


Session NotesSession = ContextInfo.getUserSession();
```

With that you will get the informations of the current user if he is already loggid in.

Instead of using

```
NotesFactory.createSession();
```

NotesFactory.createSession() does always use the servers ID with its rights.
Which i did.
You might also be able to use

```
Session NotesSession = NotesFactory.createSession(null, "user", "password");
```

but then you have to provide the username and the password.

You might also run into a Security error when you are on a development server and running the development from the workspace of eclipse.

If you see something like this on the domino servers console

> HTTP JVM: ERROR:  'java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied
>   (java.lang.RuntimePermission getProtectionDomain)' HTTP JVM:
>   :Access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getProtectionDomain) HTTP
>   JVM: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException:
>   java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied
>   (java.lang.RuntimePermission getProtectionDomain) HTTP JVM:    at
>   com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTransformer(Unknown
>   Source

You need to add some permissions to the java.policy File at the domino Server.

I added

```
grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

there.  because in that setting you are not withing the Domino java Policy shield.

After deploying to the staging system you have to check thoroughly if if works there.

Thanks for Ulrich Krause and Sven Hasselbach over at http://atnotes.de/index.php/topic,59779.0.html for their answers

Answer (score 0):

If you need some further explanations about the JVM and the security model of domino regarding the JVM read this http://www.socialbizug.org/blogs/2ec5d0ed-d04e-4b18-9610-9819fcebca79/entry/the_java_policy_file_in_ibm_domino?lang=en_us